# Copying Block of Formulas to All Sheets Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with many (variable total number) sheets which all have identical column headings and variable number of rows. On the master sheet ("Sheet1") there is a large block of formulas that I need to copy along with formatting to all other sheets. The sheets already have unique titles so it won't work to base it on sheet numbers.

I know it's easier to hardcode the formulas but that's a major task for another day (it's very, very many formulas).

I basically have to copy and paste the formula block from a completely separate workbook into "Sheet1", then copy it from that. Here's what I have so far:

```
Windows("Step Formula Base.xlsx").Activate
Columns("AK:BP").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("NA - Sourcing - HR-IT-SLS Candidate Data %28All Candidates%29.xlsx"). _
    Activate
 Range("AK1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Sheets.FillAcrossSheets_
    ws.Range ("AK:BP")
```

I'm not quite getting the FillAcrossSheets--thought it would be an easy fix but it breaks on that line. Any thoughts or help?

Thanks!

Comment: did you read the [MSDN article on the FillAcrossSheets Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840684.aspx)

Comment: Yeah that's where I got the idea, but the problem is I want this to be a flexible code that works if the total number of sheets change. I also don't want to write in the titles of each sheet because they may change (so I can't fill in an array with each title specified).

Comment: If you select all sheets, it will do the same action to all of them so do that before you paste? No coding necessary.

Comment: Amazing--spent so much time trying to solve this and it was the simplest possible answer. Yes, it worked to just select all sheets and paste the block into all initially.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
Windows("Step Formula Base.xlsx").Activate
Columns("AK:BP").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("NA - Sourcing - HR-IT-SLS Candidate Data %28All Candidates%29.xlsx"). _
    Activate
 Sheets.Select
 Range("AK1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: you may be even better served only copy the relevant rows with formulas. Doing extensively copying and pasting of entire columns (especially across multiple sheets) will be very resource intensive and slow (and may even crash Excel). For example, just copy `Range("AK1:BP100")`, or wherever the last row of formulas is.

Comment: Great idea; the problem is I have a DateValue formula as part of the block; I want to make sure that it only extends as far as the rows with text, which vary by sheet. Is there a VBA code that I could use to insert this and break it out of the formula block? This is probably really basic but I haven't found a clear answer on it either.